# Which event get fired?

Tags: asp.net

Gridview contains a first column `checkbox.Header`, that selects all checkboxes. When datarow's checkbox is checked in gridview, which control gets fired? I am trying with `onrowdatabound` event but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I *think* what I think your'e asking, I would go ahead and create the column as a templatefield, and use the TemplateHeader as the element to interact with (possible an asp:LinkButton) using the "Click" handler to go through and enable all the check boxes in codebehind.

I had done this a while back and it seemed to work OK, but I have long since lost the source for clarification.